# Prototypes and scoping in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, prototype-chain

```js
var Bar = function(a, b) {

    this.b = b - a;
    this.m2 = function() {
        return this.a / b;
    }

}

var Foo = function(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    Bar.prototype.a = a + b;
    Bar.prototype.b = a - b;
    Bar.prototype.m1 = Bar.prototype.m2;
    Bar.prototype.m2 = function() {
        return this.a * a + this.b * b;
    }
}

o1 = new Bar(1, 5);
o2 = new Foo(2, 3);

o4 = new Foo(3, 2);

r1 = o1.m1();

console.log(r1)
console.log(o1.a)
console.log(o1.b)
```

The value of r1 seems to be based off of the prototype methods set forward from the instantiation of the o2 Foo object, and not the the o4 Foo object. However, removing the o4 Foo object seems to stop the entire thing from working. Similarly, removing o2 also prevents it from working.

I feel like correct behavior would be the modification of the object Bar's prototype by o4, meaning the value returned from executing o1.m1() would be derived from the o4 Bar prototype. So,

```
return this.a * 3 + this.b * 2;
```

However this is not the case. The correct solution returns from this:
    return this.a * 2 + this.b * 3;

This seems quite counterintuitive. What properties are at work here? Why does the solution (that r1 == 22) rely on both the instantiation of o2 and o4?

EDIT: r1 should be 22. I'm trying to figure out what path I need to go down to reach this number.

Comment: Initializing inside of a constructor function the prototype object of *another* constructor is really weird. Why would you do that? Every time you instantiate a "Foo" object, the "Bar" prototype changes. There's only one of them. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's an old exam question I'm reviewing in preparation for a midterm. I don't know why you would do it otherwise.

Comment: Note that inside the Foo constructor, the "m1" property of the Bar prototype is set to the value of the "m2" property *before* the "m2" property is updated. Thus "m1" will be the "m2" property's value from before the last call to the Foo constructor.

Comment: ^ but only, untill you've instantiated your second `Foo`. Then `m1` woll be the `m2` function of the first instance of Foo.

Comment: @Thomas it has nothing to do with instances. It's changing the property value on the *prototype*.  Instances won't be affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the call to `new Bar(1, 5)`, the value of `o1.b` will be `4`. The value of `o1.m2` will be that function, but it doesn't matter; that's a red herring.

After the call to `new Foo(2, 3)`:

- `Bar.prototype.a` will be 5
- `Bar.prototype.b` will be -1 (and this will never matter)
- `Bar.prototype.m1` will be `undefined` (won't matter)
- `Bar.prototype.m2` will be a function that's effectively:

  ```
  function() {
      return this.a * 2 + this.b * 3;
  }
  ```

The `a` and `b` (as distinct from `this.a` and `this.b`) are "frozen in time" in that function, and they'll never be anything other than `2` and `3`.

After the call to `new Foo(3, 2)`:

- `Bar.prototype.a` will be 5
- `Bar.prototype.b` will be 1 (won't matter)
- `Bar.prototype.m1` will be that "m2" function above
- `Bar.prototype.m2` will be that same function, except with the local `a` being 3 and `b` being 2 (won't matter)

So when `o1.m1()` is called, we're running a function that's going to be working with the following values:

- `this.a` will be 5, because that's the most recently set value of the Bar prototype property "a"
- `this.b` will be 4, because that's the value of the "b" property on the *instance* of Bar created in the first step, and instance properties shadow prototype properties

Thus in the function

```
function() {
  return this.a * 2 + this.b * 3;
}
```

given those values we've got `5 * 2 + 4 * 3` and that's `22`.

Answer (score 0):

The question investigates multiple behaviors of JavaScript:

- local properties of an object shadow inherited properties, rendering values held in the prototype chain inaccessible,
- Closures created by nested functions use outer function variable and parameter values that were in place when the inner function was created: the lexical record chain of nested functions is different for each call to an outer function that creates them (the inner function).
- the behavior and value of `this` inside functions.

```js
var Bar = function(a, b) {

    this.b = b - a;
    this.m2 = function() {
        return this.a / b;
    }

}
// every Bar object has a local property b, and method m2
// these are not inherited
// Bar.prototype values for b and m2 will be ignored

var Foo = function(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    Bar.prototype.a = a + b;
    Bar.prototype.b = a - b;
    Bar.prototype.m1 = Bar.prototype.m2;
    Bar.prototype.m2 = function() {
        return this.a * a + this.b * b;
    }
}
// Foo is (nonsense) code that sets Foo object properties a and b
// These are not used by Bar object methods where "this" refers to the Bar object.

// Setting Bar.prototype.b has no affect as discussed under Bar.

// Although Bar.prototype.m2 is never inherited by Bar objects, it is
// a valid place to store a function value. Initially it is undefined.

// After calling Foo once, Bar.prototype.m1 is undefined.
// After calling Foo twice, Bar.prototype.m1 is
//
//    function() { return this.a * a + this.b * b}
//
// Where this.a was calculated in the most recent call to Foo,
// set on Bar.prototype, and inherited by Bar objects,
// this.b is a local property of the Bar object, and
//  a and b are the parameter values of the call to Foo which created
// the anonymous function object currently stored in  Bar.prototype.m1.


o1 = new Bar(1, 5);
//  at this point o1.b is set to 4 and does not change
//  o1.a is not in the inheritance chain and is undefined
//

o2 = new Foo(2, 3);
// at this point o1.a is inherited as 5 and o1.m1 is undefined

o4 = new Foo(3, 2);
// at this point o1.a is again inherited as 5 (the sum of 3+2)
// and o1.m1 is defined

r1 = o1.m1();
//   uses o1.a=5, o1.b=4 and the values of parameter variables a and b
//   held in the closure created by the nested m2 function inside Foo.
//
// the method function is shuffled down before arriving at Bar.prototype.m1,
// where it captures the a and b parameters of the second to last call to Foo,
// which in this example is a=2, b=3

// So the expected value of o1.m1() is
//  o1.a * a + o1.b * b
// =  5  * 2 + 4 * 3
// = 22

console.log(r1)
console.log(o1.a)
console.log(o1.b)
```